# Is it possible to call C functions from femtolisp?

Tags: julia, femtolisp

I recently came across small lisp dialect called femtolisp, written by Jeff Bezanson, the author of famous Julia Language.
(For more information about femtolisp visit https://code.google.com/p/femtolisp/ and https://github.com/JeffBezanson/femtolisp) and I really like it.

However, I wonder is there some way to call C functions from femtolisp?

Comment: In Julia's femtolisp implementation, this is (kind of) done.  See [flisp/julia_extensions.c](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/flisp/julia_extensions.c#L105-L109).  But these extensions are linked into femtolisp itself.  You can see how it assigns them to global "builtins".  Of course, this doesn't mean there may not be another, perhaps less performant, way of doing this… but this may be a start.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is currently no way to call arbitrary C functions from within the femtolisp language. As Matt B. says, there is an extension API that lets you write functions in C (which can in turn call any C function) and register them to become callable from femtolisp. It would be possible to use this mechanism to add a `ccall` function that used e.g. libffi to call any C function.